# How to fix an issue in my javascript slider range?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I'm trying to fix an issue in my JavaScript and unfortunately I'm a little stuck on where I'm going wrong here.

I'm designing a slider where the sliders thumb changes to a different range which is currently 1 - 5. The issue is that I cannot seem to get the emojis to appear as they should when the slider changes.

Here is what I'm working with:

```js
var slider = document.getElementById('myRange')

function onChange(event) {
  var x = event.target.value

  if (x <= 3) {
    slider.className = ''
  } else if (x > 3 && x <= 6) {
    slider.className = 'MyClass-1'
  } else if (x > 6) {
    slider.className = 'MyClass-2'
  } else if (x > 6) {
    slider.className = 'MyClass-3'
  }
}
```

```css
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 25px auto;
    background: #08121c;
    border: 3px solid #08121c;
    border-radius: 100px;
    display: block;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: url(http://d1cxtglzz1rb2m.cloudfront.net/emoji/SVG/18-slightly-smiling-face.svg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}

input[type="range"].MyClass-1::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background-image: url(http://d1cxtglzz1rb2m.cloudfront.net/emoji/SVG/06-grinning-face-with-smiling-eyes.svg);
}

input[type="range"].MyClass-2::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background-image: url(http://d1cxtglzz1rb2m.cloudfront.net/emoji/SVG/12-smiling-face-with-sunglasses.svg);
}

input[type="range"].MyClass-3::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background-image: url(http://d1cxtglzz1rb2m.cloudfront.net/emoji/SVG/13-smiling-face-with-heart-eyes.svg);
}
```

```html
 <div class="slider-bar">
                                            <input type="range" id="myRange" min="1" max="5" value="1" />
                              
                                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is going on with this function?:

```
function onChange(event) {
  var x = event.target.value

  if (x <= 3) {
    slider.className = ''
  } else if (x > 3 && x <= 6) {
    slider.className = 'MyClass-1'
  } else if (x > 6) {
    slider.className = 'MyClass-2'
  } else if (x > 6) {
    slider.className = 'MyClass-3'
  }
}
```

The last `else if` will never execute.

EDIT: If `x` is the integer that is the same number you want to match the class, you can simply replace all the code above with

```
slider.className = `MyClass-${x}`;
```

Comment: Seems as if I missed a line in my question `slider.addEventListener('input', onChange)`

Comment: That doesn't really clarify my confusion. Both the last `else if` statements have the same condition.

Comment: I see so there should not be else if statements which makes sense to why my emojis won't show when changing the slider range. How I'm trying to do this is if  the slider range is one it will show emoji 1 and 2 = emoji 2 and so on

Answer (score 1):

replace you JS script with this code and it should work.
however you do need to fix your if statement

```
  var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");


  slider.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
    var x = event.target.value
    console.log(x)
    if (x <= 3) {
      slider.className = ''
    } else if (x > 3 && x <= 4) {
      slider.className = 'MyClass-1'
    } else if (x > 4) {
      slider.className = 'MyClass-2'
    } else if (x > 5) {
      slider.className = 'MyClass-3'
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JS onchange event is not wired to anything. Try this

```
var slider = document.getElementById('myRange')

slider.onchange = function(event) {
  var x = event.target.value

  if (x <= 3) {
    slider.className = ''
  } else if (x > 3 && x <= 6) {
    slider.className = 'MyClass-1'
  } else if (x > 6) {
    slider.className = 'MyClass-2'
  } else if (x > 6) {
    slider.className = 'MyClass-3'
  }
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m1svk9nh/)

Your conditional statements need some work though, as they will not all be executed. Perhaps something like this:

```
slider.onchange = function(event) {
  var x = event.target.value

  if (x <= 3) {
    slider.className = ''
  } else if (x > 3 && x <= 4) {
    slider.className = 'MyClass-1'
  } else if (x > 4) {
    slider.className = 'MyClass-2'
  } else if (x > 5) {
    slider.className = 'MyClass-3'
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank I seemed to have missed out the last line of my script `slider.addEventListener('input', onChange)` however I trying to figure out the conditional statement so I'm able to show each emoji per value range